# Swap Div's using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a `Div` for `address` containing various *input box and labels*.
This `div` has a *unique ID in DOM*.

I make a `Ajax` call to get the `HTML` back containing this `Div`.

```
<script>
$("#country").on("change", function(){
    var str = $("#myform").serialize();

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        data:str,

        url:'../change/country',

    }).done(function(html) {
        $("#addressDiv").replaceWith( $(html).filter("#addressDiv") );

    });

});
```

Now I want to replace the old `Div` with the one coming in `Ajax` response.

How can I do that using `Javascript / Jquery` ?

Comment: And where is the code??

Comment: Updated question with code.

Comment: what is the contents of html you are getting as response in done functino.

Answer (score 0):

If the html response from your ajax call is just the div including the `<div>` and `</div>` tags then do this:

```
$.ajax({
   url : "your url here"
}).done(function(html) {
   $("#yourDivIdHere").replaceWith(html);
});
```

If the response just has the div's content then instead of `.replaceWith()` use:

```
   $("#yourDivIdHere").html(html);
```

If your response includes other stuff that you don't need then you can extract just the bit you want:

```
   $("#yourDivIdHere").replaceWith( $(html).filter("#yourDivIdHere") );
```

Comment: When using the filter approach, its making the div disappear. How can I fix that ?

Comment: Use one of the other approaches? I gave three options because you didn't make the structure of the ajax response clear. If you could show what the response is I could advise further.

Answer (score 0):

I would say something like

```
var html_from_ajax_request = '<b>......</b>';

jQuery('#your_div_id').html(html_from_ajax_request);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$.ajax({

  url: "your URL",

  --rest of the code--

}).done(function(data) {//An construct to the success callback option.

  $(SELECTOR).html(data);//this will change the content of the div element.

});
```